# On multiple Class#extend calls

Tags: ruby, decorator, singleton-methods

Consider a code from [this article](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/evaluating-alternative-decorator-implementations-in):

```
class Coffee
  def cost
    2
  end
end

module Milk
  def cost
    super + 0.4
  end
end

module Sugar
  def cost
    super + 0.2
  end
end

coffee = Coffee.new
coffee.extend(Milk)
coffee.extend(Sugar)
coffee.cost   # 2.6, while I expected 2.2
```

---

The reason why it's 2.6 and not 2.2 is because every call of `extend` adds a module into the instance singleton class ancestors chain, as pointed out below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`extend` adds to the list of ancestors, it doesn't replace any existing ancestors - if you examine `coffee.singleton_class.ancestors` after the second extend you can see that it includes both `Milk` and `Sugar`.

If you are running 2.2, you can use the new `super_method` method to examine this:

```
coffee.method(:cost) => #<Method: Coffee(Sugar)#cost>
```

This shows that if you call 'cost' you first go to the 'Sugar' module's implementation

```
coffee.method(:cost).super_method => #<Method: Coffee(Milk)#cost>
```

this shows that in `Sugar#cost` you call `super` then you will jump in to the method provided by `Milk`

and finally

```
coffee.method(:cost).super_method.super_method => #<Method: Coffee#cost>
```

when you call super from there you end up in the base class implementation

Comment: Well, it turns out I've overlooked the fact that Milk and Sugar get into the ancestors chain. Why would I think they don't? Thanks a lot for pointing this out.

Answer (score 0):

You always just have `#cost` which is modified by future arguments - it's not a matter of being overwritten:

```
coffee = Coffee.new
#cost is 2
coffee.extend(Milk)
#cost is 2.4
coffee.extend(Sugar)
#cost is 2.6
```

The article is saying that this implementation is the same as the other inheritance based examples that they give.

Comment: I don't understand. My assumption is that when the `cost` method **is** replaced with the same-named method from the module. You're saying two `cost` methods from the mixed in modules co-exist together? But that's not true, because `coffee.singleton_methods` returns `[:cost]` even after the second `#extend`.

Comment: no, i'm saying that they do not co-exist - when you `extend(milk)`, the original `#cost` is now `cost + 0.4` - so further extensions use that as the base

Comment: You mean the source code of the methods is concatenated? It seems unrealistic.